# Intellij database cannot create new row

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

Using IntelliJ 14.0.3, whenever I try to create a new row inside a database table, the editor just creates a new row with default values for each column. Then I edit those default values with actual values. After refreshing, the row then disappears. Auto-commit is on.

**Edit:** Also happens in IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.1
Even with Auto-Commit off, after I create the row, edit the values, then click the Commit button, it is still not saved.

Comment: Andrew is this still an issue for you? If so, what database and driver are you using?

Comment: Yes, the problem persists. MySQL driver.

Comment: Right. What version MySQL and what driver (maven dependency) and how does the jdbc url look (without real server names or password) ? Can look at it tomorrow and test it out.

Comment: Server version: 5.5.41-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 and JDBC driver: (Ubuntu)/home/user/.IntelliJIdea14/config/jdbc-drivers/mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar; The URL is jdbc:mysql://ip_addr:3306 But I had this problem for quite some time, even with a lower version MySQL. So don't quite think that's the problem. Can you at least confirm if the create works on your end with any MySQL configuration whatsoever?

Comment: Ehm, report an issue? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: Ehm, if I were to report an issue to each private project issue tracker for every tool or library that I use, I would be spammed with useless accounts that I'm never going to use again after I report that single issue. which sucks. So, tried again with latest update, still doesn't work. @vikingsteve have you been able to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Hi Andrew, sorry - havent had time. I can try on Monday.

Comment: Now even the Refresh table content action is not working anymore... Wtf is going on? It used to work.

Comment: Did you find a solution yet? I'm experiencing the same problem. Using IDEA 14.1.1 on Linux, MariaDB 15.1 (10.0.18).

Comment: Wow, finally somebody sharing the same problem. Thanks for commenting. No, haven't found any solution yet. It's pretty annoying...

Comment: thats a shame, sound like where the only 2 people on the internet that have this problem, because I cant find anything about it.. I think I'm going to submit a bug with Jetbrains, I'll post a link of it here.

Comment: Jetbrains bug report; https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-140348

Comment: Does the refresh actually work for you? It used to work fine for me for a year, until a week or two ago, when it just stop working. I would push the refresh table button, but nothing happens.

Comment: Yes, the refresh works for me, or at last looks like it because it briefly shows a "loading" icon. I'm not sure if it ever worked because this is the first time I'm using this.

Comment: Have you submitted the inserted row before refreshing? 'Submit New Row' action is available from inserted row's context menu.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After you filled new values in, you have to invoke 'Submit New Row' action - it's available in the inserted row's context menu.

The thing is, after you've hit 'Add New Row', the new row is only added in the UI, so that you can edit values. 'Submit New Row' action submits a new row to your dbms, 'Commit' commits current database transaction.

Comment: Perfect. Apparently hitting Enter after editing the values wasn't ok. Hitting Ctrl+Enter is the equivalent of the Submit new Row action from the context menu. Thanks for clearing that up. I don't think the UX is quite ok for this action, but at least it works and it isn't a bug. Any ideas though regarding why the refresh won't work?

Comment: For example, I just created a new row through the method you described. I updated a value from that row inside IntelliJ IDEA's own database console. I then clicked the Refresh button on top of the database rows UI, the spinner appeared, but the new row value didn't update. After that I closed the rows UI, entered it again and the value is changed. So I am assuming the refresh action isn't triggering the refresh logic or something.

Comment: It's due to your UPDATE and SELECT statements being executed in different transactions. Take a look at this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-140412 - I've already had this discussion today =)

Comment: @Andrew, any suggestions on UX improvement?

Comment: Understood. Wouldn't it be better if you would detect the refresh action called by the user and prompt for commit in the case of Auto-Commit off? Or something similar. Just trying to at least give a possibility for the user to comprehend what's going on behind the scenes, as to not lead him into thinking there's something wrong, like what happened with me and Gavin. And what happened with the row transaction commit.

Comment: As for the row transaction insertion UX, I would suggest 2 things: color the row in yellow until commit (I saw you color it in red if the commit fails, which is good) & add a button on the right of the row (or somewhere visible on the row) with the action of insert, in order for it to be visible, instead of tucked into the contextual menu, hidden from sight.